# score a string's similarity with others in an array

Tags: arrays, string, similarity

trying to figure out a way to score these lines of string stored in an array.  I'm thinking i should get the first 8 characters and assign them a number value.  There must be a way to change a string into a number, then after i save that to the array i should be able to have another loop flip the the score column and group anything that is w/in 10%

Any idea's welcome, below i'll post a sample copy of my data

```
2017 Parade/1st/205 Bergamont
2017 Parade/2nd/205 Bergamont
State St Station/4th WF/Area C
Contour Apt/3rd-WF/Milwaukee,WI
Contour Apt/4th-WF/Milwaukee,WI
Contour Apt/5th-WF/Milwuakee,WI
Contour Apt/6th-WF/Milwaukee,WI
Contour Apts/R-WF/Milwaukee,WI
SouthridgeApt/B2/2ndWF-P1
SouthridgeApt/Clubhouse
SouthridgeApt/B1/2ndWF-P1
SouthridgeApt/B1/2nd/WF-P2
SouthridgeApt/B1/3rdWF-P1
SouthridgeApt/B1/3rdWF-P2
SouthridgeApt/B1/Roof-P1
SouthridgeApt/B1/Roof-P2
SouthridgeApt/B2/2ndWF-P2
SouthridgeApt/B2/3rdWF-P1
SouthridgeApt/B2/3rdWF-P2
SouthridgeApt/B2/Roof-P1
SouthridgeApt/B2/Roof-P2
Breezy Hill Nursery/MenomoneeFalls
Breezy Hill Nursery/MenomoneeFalls
Courtyard by Marriott/4th-WF
Courtyard by Marriott/4th-WP
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please note SO is not a code writing service. You should describe what you've tried so far, errors and desired functionality. Aside, there are a lot of similarity algorithms (hamming distance, hashes...). Libraries depend on your language of choice.

Comment: well what i am thinking of doing is taking sub-string of each of these values, like the first 8 charicters

    //Group Projects
    o.rank = to_descrip.substring(0,8);

Comment: then i need a operation that will take the string and make it a number based on the sum of it's ascii values.  I could use some help  w/ an operator that would do that....

then i should be able to take those values and group them by how close they are